# How to do blur into blur to "backdrop-filter" in CSS?

Tags: css, css-filters

How to do blur into blur to `backdrop-filter` in CSS?

I tried `backdrop-filter:blur`, div blur it working but div inner div blur not working.

I want to give more blur to the div inside a blurry div. As an example, let the main div be 5px and the div inside is more blurred, ie 10px.

Briefly, I want to add more blur to the area marked in red.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-image:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014__340.jpg');
  background-position:center;
  background-color:green;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.bigArea {
  backdrop-filter:blur(5px);
  padding:100px;
  text-align:center;
}

.innerArea {
  backdrop-filter:blur(20px);
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="bigArea">
  Some Text
  <div class="innerArea">
    Other Some Text
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the whole div blurred but more blurred in the middle?

Comment: Yes, I want to this.

Comment: It will try to blur the background of its direct parent only , background which is not body's but bigArea's.

Comment: This is the intended behavior, see: https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#backdrop-root-image and https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#BackdropFilterProperty